# Why python3.6 could yield from a coroutine object in a non-coroutine generator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

**zz.py**

```
import asyncio

# @asyncio.coroutine
def main():
    yield from asyncio.sleep(1)

next(main())
```

- Execute in Python 3.6.7 --> OK, no error.
- Execute in Python 3.7.3 --> NOT OK, reported next:

  ```
    zz.py:5: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'sleep' was never awaited
      yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
    RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "zz.py", line 7, in <module>
        next(main())
      File "zz.py", line 5, in main
        yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
    TypeError: cannot 'yield from' a coroutine object in a non-coroutine generator
  ```

I know I could enable `@asyncio.coroutine` to make both work, or `async/await`.

But, here my question is: if I still use `generator`, what's the difference here for python3.6 & python3.7? I really feel chaos here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause after dig into the python source code:

- In python3.6, although `async/await` already there, `coroutine.sleep` still use `generator based coroutine`:

  ```
  @coroutine
  def sleep(delay, result=None, *, loop=None):
      """Coroutine that completes after a given time (in seconds)."""
      if delay == 0:
          yield
          return result

      if loop is None:
          loop = events.get_event_loop()
      future = loop.create_future()
      h = future._loop.call_later(delay,
                                  futures._set_result_unless_cancelled,
                                  future, result)
      try:
          return (yield from future)
      finally:
          h.cancel()
  ```
- In python3.7, `coroutine.sleep` starts to switch to `native coroutine`:

  ```
  async def sleep(delay, result=None, *, loop=None):
      """Coroutine that completes after a given time (in seconds)."""
      if delay <= 0:
          await __sleep0()
          return result

      if loop is None:
          loop = events.get_event_loop()
      future = loop.create_future()
      h = loop.call_later(delay,
                          futures._set_result_unless_cancelled,
                          future, result)
      try:
          return await future
      finally:
          h.cancel()
  ```

So, when python3.6 execute `yield from asyncio.sleep(1)`, it in fact did not yield from a native coroutine, surely not have error.